# In android, when is a context different from "this"?

Tags: java, android, android-context

I am at baby step level of programming on Android (and in Java in general). I do understand that Activity inherits from the Context class. However in every code snippet I have come across, every time a context must be mentionned, it is set to "this".

My question is : when is a context different from "this" ? Could you provide an real life example of context needing to be different from "this"?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Have a look at what `this` means in Java: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically, you will want to use `this` when you are "inside" of an Activity. However, when you are using for example a Helper class, the reference `this` will not work. An example can be something like this:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
    }
}
```

A case, where you cannot:

```
public class MyHelper
{
    /* some code of yours */

    public void lockOrientation(Activity activity)
    {
        activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
    }
}
```

The above code locks the orientation to the current orientation. Notice that you need to supply the method with an Activity parameter, since you cannot use:

```
this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_NOSENSOR);
```

In the first example, you could use `this` to achieve this, because you were "inside" of an Activity.

Another type of example, how do you set `onClickListener`.

First example, when you use `this`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        //handle the click event
    }
}
```

In this example, you can use `this` because in the first line, we wrote `implements View.OnClickListener`, so the class inherits from the given interface. Without the implements thingie, you couldn't do it. An example of setting the `onClickListener` without `this`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                //handle the click event
            }
        });
    }
}
```

In the second example, we are defining an `Anonymous Inner Class`, which will handle the click event of the button. Notice that in this case, our Activity does NOT `implements View.OnClickListener`.

Comment: @warm: In non-activity class you can not use "this".. while in activity class you can use "this".. rest is explained above.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question. I understand why "this" is not used in your second example. Do you have another case in mind where, within an Activity, you would pass another value than "this" as the context ?

Comment: You can globally define context variable as, Context context = this; and use variable "context" instead of "this".

Comment: See the updated answer with another example. There are loads of cases when you cannot use `this`, but this two is kinda easy to understand.

Comment: @android_beginner Careful with saving the Context in a variable, especially if it is a static one. You can really mess with the Garbage Collector, and cause serious memory leaks. Unless you don't have to, try to avoid this. :)

Answer (score 1):

Example:

```
class Example{
    int number = 0;

    public Example(int number){
        this.number = number;
    }
}
```

notice that number in the contructor and number in the class are not the same. Altough they have the same name. Saying number = number doesn't make sense. Be using this you can asses number in the class.

Answer (score 1):

1. In Outer Class you directly use "this" reference
2. In Inner Class Or Abstract Class implementation Or Interface implementation use "classname.this" reference

Answer (score 0):

For example when you are implementing an OnClickListener the "this" is different.

Comment: Yes, but you still type "this". My question was when do you not type "this" as a context. hundeva provides an answer to that. I am curious to find other examples if there are.

Comment: Inside an Activity, create a variable, Context context. Then on onCreate method you can do context=this, and later use that variable for anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

`this` is a reference to the current object — the object whose method or constructor is being called.

Inside an `Activity`'s method `this` can be used as a `Context` object because `Activity` inherits from `ContextThemeWrapper`, which inherits from `ContextWrapper`, which inherits from `Context`.

A `Fragment` on the other hand does not inherit from `Context`. So to get the `Context` inside a `Fragment` you would have to call `getActivity()` for example.

This applies to any object you are calling `this` from.

Consider you are inside the `OnClick()` method of a `View.OnClickListener` and you want to start an `Activity`:

```
button.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NextActivity.class); // wrong because 'this' is the OnClickListener object

        Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class); // correct because 'this' is the CurrentActivity object

        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: Benito, while this is great information it is not exactly what I am looking for ultimately (my question is surely ill formatted). Even though you help clear a possible confusion between different "this", in the end the code you provide uses "this" as a context and my question is when is the context different from "this". I do understand the information you provide, and I am grateful for it, but again my question is when do we avoid typing "this" as a context.